# How to display folder name and all sub folder name in dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have code to find and display name of all folder in a rootfolder:

```
private string[] GetFolderNames(string virtualDirPath)
{
    string[] Directories;
    if (Directory.Exists(virtualDirPath))
    {
        Directories = Directory.GetDirectories(virtualDirPath);
        for (int i = 0; i < Directories.Length; i++)
        {
            Directories[i] = MapUrl(Directories[i]);//map path to the folder
        }
        return Directories;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And code bind data to Dropdownlist:

```
string[] folders = GetFolderNames(RootPath);
if (folders != null)
{
     dropDownListFolders.DataSource = folders;
     dropDownListFolders.DataBind();
}
else
{
     dropDownListFolders.Items.Insert(0, "No folders available..");
}
```

As the code above, the Dropdownlist display all the folder name in the `Rootfolder` with path= `virtualDirPath`;

But I wonder if in every child folder still has some subfolder, and in each subfolder has some more subfolder and so on more and more, so that how can I get all the name of that subfolders.

Try to make more `for` loop inside the first one, but it really mess me up. And it seems that is not the good way.

I need the Dropdownlist display all the subfolder name, child of sudfolder and child of child folder... in the rootfolder. Help! I need your opinion to find a better way to to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List<string> dirList = new List<string>();

DirectoryInfo[] dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\Path").GetDirectories("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach(DirectoryInfo d in dir) 
{
    dirList.Add(d.Name);
}

for (int i = 0; i < dirList.Count; i++) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(dirList[i]);
}
```

Try this, and get all the folder names in `dirList` and add it into the dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

Its easier if you use the inbuild Directory.EnumerateDirectories method.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/dd383462(v=vs.110).aspx

You just call it like this:

```
Directory.EnumerateDirectories("rootpath", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

This will give you an IEnumerable of the all directories ("*") with its full path. 
The enum SearchOption.AllDirectories is saying you want your search to be recursive.
The rootpath is your starting point.

Additional you could filter this method by extending the second paramater like this:

```
Directory.EnumerateDirectories("rootpath", "test*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

This will result in a IEnumerable of all directories starting with test ("test*")

**Edit:**

You should consider displaying relative paths, instead of only names which can result in duplicate list entries.

```
var directories = (from x in Directory.EnumerateDirectories("rootpath", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                    select x.SubString("rootpath".Length)).ToList();
```

Comment: @VyClarks ?!? thats exactly how you get it, when you specify SearchOption.AllDirectories, you are receiving them all. Where is your problem?

Comment: as you recommended. Directory.EnumerateDirectories("rootpath", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories); return a num of folder. But exactly I want is the name of all folder.

Comment: Its not really a wise decision to only display the name of a directory, imagine the same name existing multiple times you will have a list with duplicate entries. I would recommend you to at least output the relative path instead of only the name.

Answer (score 0):

Use following method to get list of All the folders:

```
 public void traverse(File file, List<String> dirList) {
    // Print the name of the entry
    System.out.println(file);


    // Check if it is a directory
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        System.out.println(file);
        //add directory name in the list
        dirList.add(file.getName());
        // Get a list of all the entries in the directory
        String entries[] = file.list();

        // Ensure that the list is not null
        if (entries != null) {
            // Loop over all the entries
            for (String entry : entries) {
                // Recursive call to traverse
                traverse(new File(file, entry),dirList);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

once you get the list of directory and sub directories bind it with dropdown. 
Use following code to call this method

```
 DirectoryList directoryList = new DirectoryList();

    //output pram
    ArrayList<String> dirList = new ArrayList<String>();

    directoryList.traverse(new File("D:\\Workspace\\Netbeans\\addapp"), dirList);
```